# How to show data in column with title in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Can anybody tell me how to show data in columns with a top title. Infect i am trying to show data like this:

```
ID  Name  No.  Tel No.  From Date   To Date
1   Sam                  20-10-2009  13-06-2011
2          12            20-10-2009  30-06-2011
3                5643    20-10-2009  13-06-2011
```

the XML that i am using is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/widget87"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/widget71"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>
<TableRow
android:id="@+id/widget72"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/widget33"
android:layout_width="26px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="ID"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/widget34"
android:layout_width="46px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Name"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/widget35"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Number"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/widget36"
android:layout_width="51px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Ac.Tel"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/widget37"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="From Date"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/widget38"
android:layout_width="62px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="To Date"
>
</TextView>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
android:id="@+id/widget79"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/t1"
android:layout_width="10dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Accountid"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/t2"
android:layout_width="40dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="AccountName"
android:textStyle="bold"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/t3"
android:layout_width="10dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="AccountNo"
android:textStyle="bold"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/t4"
android:layout_width="30dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="AccountTel"
android:textStyle="bold"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/t5"
android:layout_width="60dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="FromDate"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/t6"
android:layout_width="60dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="ToDate"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/t7"
android:layout_width="30dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Notes"
>
</TextView>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Problem in it is that it shows the top title each time on record like:

```
  ID  Name  No.  Tel No.  From Date   To Date
    1   Sam                  20-10-2009  13-06-2011

  ID  Name  No.  Tel No.  From Date   To Date
    2          12            20-10-2009  30-06-2011

  ID  Name  No.  Tel No.  From Date   To Date
    3                5643    20-10-2009  13-06-2011
```

So plz help me i got stuck here i am very new in android.

my new XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/widget143"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<TableRow
android:id="@+id/widget144"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="23px"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/widget146"
android:layout_width="24px"
android:layout_height="18px"
android:text="ID"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/widget147"
android:layout_width="48px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Name"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/widget149"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Number"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/widget150"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Ac. Tel."
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/widget151"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="From Date"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/widget152"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="To Date"
>
</TextView>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
android:id="@+id/widget153"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50px"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/t1"
android:layout_width="10dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Accountid"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/t2"
android:layout_width="40dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="AccountName"
android:textStyle="bold"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/t3"
android:layout_width="10dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="AccountNo"
android:textStyle="bold"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/t4"
android:layout_width="30dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="AccountTel"
android:textStyle="bold"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/t5"
android:layout_width="60dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="FromDate"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/t6"
android:layout_width="60dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="ToDate"
>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/t7"
android:layout_width="30dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Notes"
>
</TextView>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

But still there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

use **TableLayout** and **TableRow** instead of **RelativeLayout**.